# DMA of data in socket buffer (skb) in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was going through the process of packet transmission and packet reception in latest linux kernel. I can see that, there is a framework in skb where it supports "linear" data as well as "paged" data.

It has a separate structure called **skb_shared_info** to represent page fragments.

Now my doubt is, how will the device DMA the entire contents of the packet? Is it not going to be scattered across the memory?

Thanks
CHID

Comment: That is where then [IOMMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU) plays a role.

Comment: @0x90 Thanks for giving that hint. If you could provide it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the capability of the networking hardware.  Most “modern” NICs can do gather/scatter DMA and handle tranferring a packet into multiple, non-contiguous buffers, but the Linux kernel networking stack will only give an skb with nonlinear data to a driver/netdev if `NETIF_F_SG` is set (indicating the device can handle scatter/gather).  If the device driver sets `NETIF_F_SG` then it is telling the stack that it can handle multiple physical buffers per packet.

Comment: Thanks! So if the device does not support scatter gather, the stack creates individual SKB's till it meets the length of the packet is it?

Comment: It will create one skb per packet, with all the data in the linear part.